# how to specify an specific texbox to fill in c# in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I have several textboxs and buttons in my C# application  . Im using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 . In my app user can add a name to database ! for example by pressing Button1 , the name in texbox1 , will insert into database  !
I want afteruser press Button1 , he fill texbox1 again to insert another item without he will have to select texbox1 by mouse or tab ...
I want app indicate texbox1  automaticly .

Answer (score 2):

(If I understand you correctly) In the button click event just do something like the below.

```
textBox1.Clear();
if(!textBox1.Focused) 
{
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

(Winforms)

Comment: add something like textBox1.Clear();

Comment: No need to check if it's not focused, but instead you could check if it can focus `if (textBox1.CanFocus) { textBox1.Focus(); }`.